# Asyctask generating future task exception

Tags: android, logcat

I want to create a reminder

I have created a database. Database stores date and time. upto here everything is working.
Now, I want to run an `asynctask` in background which checks after every few seconds  if there is new reminder if yes then call to another activity using intent that generate `notificaton`. Also for checking in to database it is calling a different activity. I have created an infinite while loop so that it keeps on checking.

here is code.In this I am comparing current date and time with the date date and time stored in database.The complete logic of comparison is written in reminder activity.Create_notification is an Activity data has the logic of creating notification

```
public class Async_task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>{

MainActivity async_task_context = null;

public Async_task(MainActivity context) {
    async_task_context = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("in async task", "msg");
    while(1<2){

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int current_day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Log.d("in do in background", "");
        int cuurent_month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int current_year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int curent_hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int current_minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        String date = current_day+"/"+cuurent_month+"/"+current_year;
        String time = curent_hour+":"+current_minute;
        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        Reminder fetch_info = new Reminder(async_task_context);
        fetch_info.open();
        arr = fetch_info.fetch(date,time);
        fetch_info.close();
        Log.d("arr in oncreate", ""+arr);
        int size = arr.size();
        if(size !=0){
        Intent in = new Intent(async_task_context,Create_notification.class);
        in.putExtra("information", arr);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(9000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }   return arr;


    }
```

On running `logcat` I came across the following errors

```
08-30 18:13:18.701: E/AndroidRuntime(797): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-30 18:13:18.701: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-30 18:13:18.701: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
08-30 18:13:18.701: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-30 18:13:18.701: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-30 18:13:18.701: E/AndroidRuntime(797): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-30 18:13:18.701: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
08-30 18:13:18.701: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.Itspark.smartreminder.Reminder.<init>(Reminder.java:74)
08-30 18:13:18.701: E/AndroidRuntime(797):  at com.Itspark.smartreminder.Async_task.doInBackground(Async_task.java:36)
```

Below is reminder class.Reminder class is creating database and it has many methode.

```
public class Reminder extends Activity{
public static final String Column_Id="_Id";
private static final String name = "Event_Name";
private static final String date = "Event_date";
private static final String time = "Event_time";
private static final String location = "Event_location";


private static final String Table_Name="Data_container";
private static final String Database_Name="Data_Ship";
private static final int Version=1;


private Context ourcontext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourSQLiteDatabase;
private DbHelper ourHelper;





private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Database_Name, null, Version);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {



        Log.d("in on create", "before");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ Table_Name + "(" +Column_Id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + name +" TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + date +" TEXT NOT NULL, "+ time +" TEXT NOT NULL, "+ location +" TEXT );");
        Log.d("in on create", "");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Table_Name);
        onCreate(db);
    }



}


   public Reminder(Context c) {  //**This is line 74**
   ourcontext = c;

   }

public Reminder open(){
ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourcontext);
ourSQLiteDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
return this;

}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}


    public ArrayList<String> fetch(String date2, String time2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    String anArray[] = new String[] {Column_Id,name,date,time,location};
    Cursor cu = ourSQLiteDatabase.query(Table_Name, anArray, date+" =?"+" AND "+time+" =?", new String[] {date2,time2}, null, null, null);
    Log.d("after cursor","ere");

    int name1=cu.getColumnIndex(name);
    int date1 = cu.getColumnIndex(date);
    int time1 = cu.getColumnIndex(time);
    int location1 = cu.getColumnIndex(location);
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(cu.moveToFirst();!cu.isAfterLast();cu.moveToNext()){
        arr.add("Name "+cu.getString(name1)+ "\nDate "+cu.getString(date1)+"\nTime "+cu.getString(time1)+"\nLocation "+cu.getString(location1));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: try commenting out the `sleep`. What do u get ?

Comment: After commenting sleep I am getting same exception

Comment: What does the `Reminder` class do? Specifically, what is on `line 74` of `Reminder.java`?

Comment: It's your `Reminder` class causing this issue. Specifically, it seems it has a `Handler` as a member variable. Since the async task thread is not supposed to contain an event loop (`Looper`), you're trying to do something you're not supposed to do in a background thread.

Comment: no,Reminder class do no has handler.Plz check updated post

Comment: @user2733908 `Reminder` is an `Activity` then you attempt to use it like a plain old Java Object, that may be the issue. Keep non-Activity functions separate from your Activity functions. Make `Reminder` a class that does *not* extend `Activity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `Thread.sleep` in:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
public void run(){
Thread.sleep();
}
});
```

Comment: Sleeping in the _UI_ thread is even worse and should never be done.

Comment: @A--C then what should I do?

Comment: @user2733908 are you _sure_ that this solved the problem? It is likely to cause more trouble than it's worth (depending on how much you sleep, your application may "Stop Responding", plus this seems quite unrelated). Plus both laalto and I think it's something in the `Reminder` class.

Comment: Please tell me wat to do is there is another way to achieve what I want

Comment: @user2733908 You can start by posting the `Reminder` class and highlighting line 74 as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't Sleep in `doInBackground()`. Rather you should move this code to `OnPostExecute`

Or you can use `runOnUiThread` just what the other answer suggested.

Comment: Sleeping in the _UI_ thread is even worse and should never be done.

Answer (score 0):

U can't access the UI thread from doinbackground method.u need the post execute method in a sync task to perform any task on main UI thread. U can pass the array list to the post execute and can perform the rest of the work from there